# imagemagick / ghostscript Error on conversion

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

We are using imagemagick to convert PDFs to JPEGs. Using the code below:

```
shell_exec('convert source.pdf output.jpg');
```

Im getting this error:

```
Segmentation fault
convert: Postscript delegate failed `/var/www/location/source.pdf':  @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/663.
convert: missing an image filename `/var/www/location/output.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011.
```

And works most of the time. There are some PDFs though that we can convert. Those are with alot of text and tables have some problem and do not convert at all.

I used GS script to convert and same thing. It does not convert.

```
shell_exec('gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o output.jpg source.pdf');
```

- Is there any way to convert those pdfs to jpg using imagemagick/gs?
- What are things to avoid on pdf so that it will be converted to jpg using imagemagick/gs?

Comment: You say "I used GS script to convert and same thing. It does not convert." in what way 'does not convert' ? Do you get an error ? If so, what ? If not, then what **is** the problem ? Which version of Ghostscript are you using ? Most likely your PDF files are broken in some way, its not going to be possible to tell you anything more without looking at the PDF files, so where we can we download one of your problematic files to examine ? The obvious answer to 'things to avoid' would be 'Dont' create broken PDF files :-)

Comment: You might also like to try just running Ghostscript from the shell, so you can see what it says.

Comment: What version of Ghostscript are you using? If old, then perhaps get the most current one.